# Java Null PointerException. Trying to implement semaphores

Tags: java, semaphore

I have been working on this code for days. And I am trying to figure out what is the problem. I am implementing semaphores and how they choose between read and write processes, for this case the read `mu` processes are more important and thus have more priority. And I think my `Semaphore` class is giving the problem and not the main method. The exception is at line 29 in the Semaphore class which has this code `for (int i = 0; i < updatedProcessArray.length; i++)`

I have random 0's and 1's, the 0's are read processes and the 1's are write processes. The Assumption in my program is that all processes comes at the same time and because the readers `0` always have more priority they will always be processed first. When a processes is finished a -1 will mark their array index. The program loops through the array until every thing in the array is negative -1, well that was the objective.

Semaphore class

```
class Semaphore
{
    public int [] updatedProcessArray; // initializing array for update
    public int readcount = 0; // keep track of sharedData process

    public int signal; // process signal on 00 for reader, on for 01 writer, 10 wait for reader, 11 wait for writer.
    //public int priortyReader = 0; // priorty check for readers, with 1 being priorty
   public int processesCompleted = 0;


    //Semaphore constructor
    Semaphore(int[] processArray)
    {
        int[] updatedProcessArray = processArray.clone(); // copy array     
    }

    public int signalQueue(int muxtex, int wrt, int index)
    {
        int mu = muxtex; // assgining all process semaphore
        int wr = wrt; // assigning writer semahpore
        int currentIndex = index; // index for current process
        int priorityIndex = 0; // index for priority
      int priorityReader = 0;
        int minimumWriterIndex = 0; // index of lowest writer (writer with the highest priority)

      //int array[];
        // loop through array
        for (int i = 0; i < updatedProcessArray.length; i++)
        {
            // Checking the top priority in the queue

            //independent if statement
            if (wr == updatedProcessArray[i] && currentIndex == i)
            {
                if (minimumWriterIndex != 1)
                    minimumWriterIndex = 1; // record first index with writer
            }

            if (mu == updatedProcessArray[i] &&  currentIndex == i)
            {
                //priorityIndex = 0;
                //signal = 00; // the priority has been found, reader.


                // As soon as the first priority is found reader priorty is found,
                // there is no greater priorty in the queue 
                //priorityReader = 1; // all reader processes have priority over writer processes
                //priorityIndex = i; // recording the priority index
                return (updatedProcessArray[i] = -1); // marking off to show that job being processed. 


            }
            else
            {
                if (mu == updatedProcessArray[i])
                    // keeping track of readers
                    priorityReader = 1; // to show all reader processes have priority over writer processes

            }       
        }

        if (priorityReader != 1 && minimumWriterIndex == 1)
           return (updatedProcessArray[minimumWriterIndex] = -1);

      return 0;             
    } 

    public int waitQueue(int mutex, int wrt, int index)
    {
        // declaring variables
        int mu = mutex;
        int wr = wrt;
        int currentIndex = index;

        if (readcount < 1)
        {
            // comparing current index value with semaphore mutex
            if (mu == updatedProcessArray[currentIndex])
            {
                signal = 10;
                return signal; //reader process waiting
            }
            // comparing current index value with semaphore wrt
            if (wr == updatedProcessArray[currentIndex])
            {
                signal = 11; //writer process waiting
                return signal;
            }
            return 0;
        }
      return 0;
    }
    // for our purpose Signal method will be used for wait as well
    public int signal()
    {
        if (signal == 00 || signal == 01)
      {
            readcount++;
         return signal;
      }


        if (signal == 10 || signal == 11)
      {
            readcount--;
           return signal;
      }
      return 0;
    }
   public int getProcessesCompleted()
   {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < updatedProcessArray.length; i++)
      {
         if (updatedProcessArray[i] == -1)
            sum++; // update sum   
      }
      return sum;   
   }
   public int[] updateArray()
   {
      return updatedProcessArray;
   }
}
```

main method

```
import java.util.Random;

    class SemaphoreTest
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Random rn = new Random(); // creating a new random object

            int processArraySize = rn.nextInt(11); // size of processArray

            int[] processArray = new int[processArraySize]; // giving array size

            int mutex = 0; // semaphore for readers
            int wrt = 1; // semaphore for writers

            // Now we will initialize populate processArray
            for (int i = 0; i < processArraySize; i++)
            {
                int x = rn.nextInt(2); // we will denote 0 as reader and 1 as writer
                processArray[i] = x; // assigning x to index i

            }

            Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(processArray); // creating a new semaphore object
            int signal = 0;

          int processCompleted = 0;
            while(processCompleted < processArraySize)
            {
                // return the new and updated processArray each time
                // a -1 will be where the processes have been completed
                // the process will continue untill all process have been completed only -1's in the array


                for (int i = 0; i < processArraySize; i++)
                {


                    semaphore.signalQueue(mutex, wrt, i); // calling mutex semaphore and wrt semaphore
                signal = semaphore.signal();
                if (signal == 00)
                {
                   System.out.println("reader: using shared data \t index: " + i 
                      + "number of processe(s) completed: " + semaphore.getProcessesCompleted() );
                }
                if (signal == 01)
                {
                   System.out.println("writer: using shared data \t index: " + i 
                      + "\tnumber of processe(s) completed: " + semaphore.getProcessesCompleted() );
                }
                // wait semaphore
                    semaphore.waitQueue(mutex, wrt, i); // calling mutex semaphore and wrt semaphore
                if (signal == 10)
                {
                   System.out.println("reader: waiting to access shared data \t index: " + i 
                      + "number of processe(s) completed: " + semaphore.getProcessesCompleted() );
                }
                if (signal == 10)
                {
                   System.out.println("writer: waiting to access shared data \t index: " + i 
                      + "number of processe(s) completed: " + semaphore.getProcessesCompleted() );
                }
                }//end of for loop

             // updating process completed
             processCompleted = semaphore.getProcessesCompleted();

          }//end of while loop

       }//end of method   
    }
```

Comment: First, please provide a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Keyword minimal. Don't paste your whole code, give us the SMALLEST possible version of your code that still reproduces the problem. And second, if you want us to debug an exception at least say what line it occurs on.

Comment: Sorry sir what is an MVCE? where should I put my code? the exception is at line 29

Comment: If you want to know what an MVCE is click the link in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the constructor Semaphore,You must refer to the class attribute with the keyword this should not create a new array as you work with the array `updatedProcessArray`

change

```
Semaphore(int[] processArray)
    {
        int[] updatedProcessArray = processArray.clone(); // copy array     
    }
```

to

```
Semaphore(int[] processArray)
    {
        this.updatedProcessArray = processArray.clone(); // copy array     
    }
```

an additional recommendation could use a switch structure to avoid many if

```
     switch(signal)
            {
                case 00: System.out.println("reader: using shared data \t index: " + i 
                  + "number of processe(s) completed: " + semaphore.getProcessesCompleted() );break;
                case 01:instruction;break;
                case 02: instruction;break;
                default: not option
            }
```

Comment: I could mark my answer, if I fix your inconvenience

Comment: Hi sorry, I was going to thumb you up! it is compiling now and running, just fixing up a few things so it can run as it should. The `this.updatedProcessArray ` really helped.